# OrderByChild, equalTo and limitToFirst query loading whole database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a regional dictionary app in firebase.

Data Structure image : [Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwxcN.png)

OrderByKey and limitToFirst query for pagination working fine, it's loading the queried data only. Code sample below -

```
db.ref('dictionary')
  .orderByKey()
  .startAt(String(this.perpage * (this.page - 1) + 1))
  .limitToFirst(this.perpage)
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => {
    vm.words = []
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key
      var childData = childSnapshot.val()
      childData.id = childKey
      vm.words.push(childData)
    })
    vm.inProgress = false
  })
```

But, when I'm querying using `orderByChild('word').equalTo(search_query).limitToFirst(3)` , it's fetching all the 176023 records at once(inspected from websocket). Sample code below -

```
db.ref('dictionary')
  .orderByKey()
  .orderByChild('word')
  .equalTo(this.search + '')
  // .startAt(String(25 * (this.page - 1) + 1))
  .limitToFirst(3)
  .on('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot)
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childKey = childSnapshot.key
      var childData = childSnapshot.val()
      childData.id = childKey
      vm.words.push(childData)
    })
    vm.inProgress = false
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
    vm.inProgress = false
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you don't have an index on `word`. When there is no index, the server sends the entire location to the client and the client then filters. In that case you'll also get a quite explicit warning in your JavaScript console.

See the [section in the Firebase documentation on how to define indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).